# Does Kabbalas Shabbos require a minyan?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tzibur-community, tefillah-betzibbur, kabbalat-shabbat

Inspired by an [answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35207/17563):

Does the recitation of Kabbalas Shabbos require a minyan?

I was always under the impression that we do it together by convention rather than necessity, but one could *lechatchila* recite Kabbalas Shabbos at home, and join the minyan for *Maariv*. This [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35207/17563) sounds like there is some sort of significance in 10 people.

Is there any source for this, either way?

Comment: This isn't specifically 10 but Rambam (Shabbos 30,2) says that Chachamim would gather their students together to go and greet shabbos.

Comment: I would think the only items in kabbalah shabbos that require a minyan are the kaddishes.

Comment: This is a very interesting question and I think its answer has some major affects on *Kabbalat Shabbat* meaning when does one accept Shabbat in terms of the prohibition of *melacha*. O.C. among other sources indicates that one accepts Shabbat on recitation of *Mizmor Shir Leyom Hashabbat*. And there are many sources that explain that one has to accept Shabbat when the *tzibbur* does (when there is just 1 shul in the neighborhood.) To me, that implies that the prayer *Kabbalat Shabbat* does require a tzibbur (minyan.)

Comment: How could it? None of the 3 daily tefillot require a minyan, how could a collection of tehillim and songs that only dates to the 16th century?

Comment: @DanF - I wonder if that is connected. The fact that this at the time of *mizmor shir* is, as far as I know, convention. If the *tzibbur* would accept Shabbos together before Mizmor Shir, or if they would choose to do so by *borchu* (see the commentaries on OC there, IIRC), it would have the same effect. This doesn't prove anything about the *tefilla* of Kabbalas Shabbos; it just shows that there is a type of *kaballas shabbos* which can be done by a *tzibbur* together.

Comment: That analysis is correct. I went www.beureihatefilah.com, one of my main *tefillah* references. Indeed, Rav AMram & Rav Sa'adiah Gaon don't even mention the tefillah Kabbalat Shabbat, and thus acceptance of Shabbat was done at another point. However, common current *halacha* is to make it at the point of reciting *Mizmor Shir*. So, I'm uncertain that if an individual reciting this has officially accepted Shabbat. I'm surmising the answer is "yes", but, I haven't been able to conclude it.

Comment: @JoshK the question remains if there's benefit to having 10 like with the main prayers

Comment: I assume they sent 10 people as a way of maintaining *Kabbalas Shabbos* as part of the customary communal liturgy, not that it requires a minyan strictly speaking.

Comment: @DoubleAA is there anything we do lirtugically that we don't believe there is benefit to doing with a minyan? AFAIK we certainly prefer to do the 3 main prayers and Mussaf with 9 other men but also benching and even tehillim. Is there anything we don't prefer it for?

Comment: @Josh Tehillim? Bentching? I don't know why you say that.

Comment: @Double AA for bentching there are additional sections to be said when bentching with an entire minyan...do we not always seek to say as many addional sections of all prayers as we are permitted to? I don't have a source on Tehillim, though, just something I read somewhere

Comment: @JoshK I've never heard of a rule to try to say as many sections of something as possible.

Answer (score 4):

At least during the pandemic, Rabbi Mordechai Willig shlit'a has led Kabbalas Shabbos up until *Mizmor Shir* on Zoom, with guitar. (From [KolCorona](https://7d4ab068-0603-408d-89df-fac4580e17c4.filesusr.com/ugd/8b9b1c_a31ae6c43d264fcb9f3edc94c85a1d65.docx?dn=Rav%20Willig%20Shlita-%20Korona%20Shaylos.docx)). Which strongly implies not a minyan.

> בפראג נהגו לערוך קבלת שבת בכלי שיר ואמרו מזמור שיר ליום השבת בתנאי שלא מקבלים שבת ואח"כ חזרו הביתה להתכונן לקראת שבת ושוב חזרו לבהכ"נ לקבל שבת באמירת מזמור שיר ליום השבת פעם שנית (קובץ בית אהרן וישראל תשרי-חשון תשנ"ח עמ' קיט-קלד). ועד היום אומרים שם מזמור שיר ליום השבת פעמיים, רצופים (מפי דר. שניאור ליימן נ"י). וא"כ מותר לערוך קבלת שבת ע"י זום, בתנאי שלא לקבל שבת. ולכן נראה שלא יעמדו לפנות אחורה כנהוג, ועדיף שלא יאמרו מזמור שיר ליום השבת אף שמותר מדינא. וכן אני נוהג בתקופה זו כל ערב שבת, בכלי שיר לחיזוק, תפלת מנחה, וקבלת שבת עד בואי כלה בלי לעמוד ולהתהפך, הכל ע"י זום.

> In Prague they would say kabbolas shabbos with instruments, intending to accept shabbos later ... so I do during this [pandemic] era every Friday afternoon, with a musical instrument for emotional strengthening, Mincha and Kabalas Shabbos until *Bo'i Kala* -- without rising and turning around, all on Zoom.

Answer (score 0):

There's one practice that I have seen that implies that a minyan is not required for *Kabbalat Shabbat*.

If I recall correctly, our shul had exactly 10 people for the minyan. An *avel* (mourner) came to shul and davened mincha Fri. evening. Just prior to Kabbalat Shabbat, the rabbi asked him to leave the shul and he returned just pior to reciting *Mizmor Shir Leyom Hashabbat* (Psalm 92.) This is because Kabbalat Shabbat is considered a "separate service", and technically, it is "not yet Shabbat " (We have a M.Y. question explaining this - I have to locate it.) so that person is still "in mourning display mode." Once Shabbat, is "official", which occurs with reciting Psalm 92, the mourner accepts Shabbat and he may not display public mourning.

The point is, that this action indicates that a minyan is not needed to say *Kabbalat Shabbat*.

There is a separate angle as to whether the recitation of Psalm 92 is the only method to indicate Shabbat acceptance, and even when used, does an individual reciting that Psalm accept Shabbat, or is it only for a *tzibbur*. I will try to edit that argument in, later.

Comment: I think you are referring to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94660/3483) and [this article](http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/0035-0052.pdf).